# how do i substitute text for a variable in a terraform?

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I'm new to terraform and wanted to substitute the value devcert below for a variable value called env, how do i format the below to include the variable value instead of devcert?

pfx_blob = data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.devcert.value

// Get Certificate from External KeyVault

```
resource "azurerm_app_service_certificate" "cert" {
  name                = "sslCertificate"
  resource_group_name = "rg1"
  location            = "uk west"
  pfx_blob            = data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.devcert.value
```

Comment: im going through that now, it requires Basic Permissions In Azure Devops and once i get those permissions i can test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that. Such operation is **not supported** in terraform. Instead you should use [for_each](https://www.terraform.io/language/meta-arguments/for_each) to create multiple instances of `azurerm_key_vault_secret`, rather then fully separate data sources. Then you can reference it using:

```
pfx_blob = data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.devcert["myinstance"].value
```

Comment: how would you do the For Each part?

Comment: @itye1970 It depends on your actual code, which you haven't shown.

Comment: // Get Certificate from External KeyVault
resource "azurerm_app_service_certificate" "cert" {
  name                = "sslCertificate"
  resource_group_name = "rg1"
  location            = "uk west"
  pfx_blob            = data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.devcert.value

Comment: @itye1970 Please update the question with correctly formatted new code.